# Python + selenium throws an error while clicking on the last next button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python with selenium to parse the name from a site. The site has got "next" button to get to its' next page. I've tried to manage this to run my script flawlessly. However, I'm facing two issues at this moment:

1. Upon execution the scraper gets to the next page and parses from there leaving the starting page unscraped because i could not fix the logic.
2. When it doesn't find the last grayed out next button it throws an error breaking the code.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&page=10")

while True:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li/a[contains(@class,"next")]')))

    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li/a[contains(@class,"next")]')
    if not driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li/a[contains(@class,"next")]'):
        break
    item.click()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="info"]')))

    for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="info"]'):
        name = items.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]').text
        print(name)

driver.quit()
```

Here is the element for grayed out next button:

```
<div class="pagination"><p><span>Showing</span>361-388
of 388<span>results</span></p><ul><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&amp;page=12" data-page="12" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132}" data-remote="true" class="prev ajax-page" data-impressed="1">Previous</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&amp;page=9" data-page="9" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:9}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">9</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&amp;page=10" data-page="10" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:10}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">10</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&amp;page=11" data-page="11" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:11}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">11</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&amp;page=12" data-page="12" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:12}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">12</a></li><li><span class="disabled">13</span></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you should try to switch *scraping page* and *clicking 'Next' button*. Also you might use `try`/`except` to avoid braking code:

```
while True:
    # Scraping required elements first
    items = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="info"]')))
    for item in items:
        name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@itemprop="name"]').text
        print(name)
    # ...and then try to click 'Next' button
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li/a[contains(@class,"next")]').click()
    except:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your invaluable solution. It always rocks. Btw, changing "of_all_elements" to "of_element" the scraper runs smoothly